# How to check in PayPal is payment valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, paypal

After payment I get the next URL:

```
http://www.website.com/en/success?tx=some_value&st=Completed&amt=some_value&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=
```

With this variables in _GET, can I check is payment valid or not? So, is user pay for this or he just randomly create URL by himself?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up an [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) solution.

Comment: I set up my IPN, but what else I need to do?

Comment: IPN will be triggered any a transaction occurs on your PayPal account, so you can add logic into your IPN script that automatically updates your database, sends email notifications, or whatever you need when the IPN hits.